# Remaining discharge time - Windows 10 Universal App C#

Tags: c#, windows, time

I have following code:

```
TimeSpan RemDisTime = Windows.System.Power.PowerManager.RemainingDischargeTime;
```

And when I disconnect the notebook charger, until the system does not estimate the time (until the will decrease by 1%) displayed radical value (2h 34min(21% battery) for me).

how to check that the system has not yet estimated the length of discharge?

Comment: Just subscribe to the [RemainingDischargeTimeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.power.powermanager.remainingdischargetimechanged) event. Then you will be notified when it is updated. You could then keep track of how long you were last updated.

Comment: Yes, but what which in the case when the application was started before now? Wait even up to 5 minutes (when the battery is good) for a change every launch the app?